# Assigning 2D string arrays using char *

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to assign a 2D array of strings in the following way:

```
char *text_data[10][4]; //10 rows, 4 columns

//All rows need to be same
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    strcpy(text_data[i][0], "a");
    strcpy(text_data[i][1], "xyz");
    strcpy(text_data[i][2], "b");
    strcpy(text_data[i][3], "xyz");  
}
```

However, this doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is no different to `char *one_string; strcpy(one_string, "xyz");`.  See the problem?

Comment: I suggest to think in terms of _arrays of char_ a not in terms of strings, there are no strings in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strcpy will only copy to a preallocated buffer so try this

```
char text_data[10][4][4];
```

If you have a double array of String you essentially have a triple array because a string is an array of char.

Comment: This can only hold strings of `size <=4`.

Comment: Well yeah this solution is for his problem. So it can hold strings of length 3 + null character. You can change the 4 or use malloc.

Answer (score 2):

`char *text_data[10][4];` is matrix of pointer, each location can point a string.

but you do not initialize or allocate memory so you can't call string copy.

You can do like:

```
 text_data[i][0] = "a";
 text_data[i][1] = "xyz";
```

**Second:** I also feel you wanted to  declare `text_data` as:

```
char text_data[10][4];
```

because every string is of length 3 or less, then do like:

```
strcpy(text_data[0], "a");
strcpy(text_data[1], "xyz");
strcpy(text_data[2], "b");
strcpy(text_data[3], "xyz");
```

**No** need of loop

Comment: At the latter part, no I did not want char text_data[10][4] because that becomes a single dimension for strings... I want a 2D string array....

Comment: @Scranton yes I just read again you answer, are you still looking for an answer Logan Murphy given you correct declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your code should look like this, no restrictions on string length. No 3D arrays of chars. But I'm rather new to programming and can be wrong, if so-correct me.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *text_data[10][4]; //10 rows, 4 columns
    int i;
//All rows need to be same
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        text_data[i][0]= "a";
        text_data[i][1]="xyz";
        text_data[i][2]= "b";
        text_data[i][3]= "xyz";  
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        puts(text_data[i][0]);
        puts(text_data[i][1]);
        puts(text_data[i][2]);
        puts(text_data[i][3]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I understand what your code is trying to do.  Have re-written it as:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        // allocate 40 uninitialized pointers to char strings
    char *text_ptr[10][4]; //10 rows, 4 columns

        int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    // essentially, copy ptr to string literal into an array element
        text_ptr[i][0] = "a";
        text_ptr[i][1] = "xyz";
        text_ptr[i][2] = "b";
        text_ptr[i][3] = "xyz";

        // print two elements from each row for a quick check
        printf("\n%s, %s", text_ptr[i][0], text_ptr[i][1]); fflush(stdout);

      }

     } // end of main;
     // Note.  This code WAS tested in an Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler environment.
```

`strcpy()` depends on an area for the string to be allocated, so that it can copied into.  In the above code there is an array of char pointers, each of them is set to the address of the literal that is being assigned.

In this code you cannot update the assigned strings.  If you want to modify the strings then you will need to do a `malloc()` for each of the 40 ([10][4]) pointers, and each `malloc()` needs to be for the length (or max length) of the string to be assigni.e. associated with that pointer element.